# Can I get restaurants contacts details from a list of entity name and addresses with Google API?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api

I have list of deliveroo restaurants with names and postal addresses, I want to call one of Google APIs to get their phone number...

I found documentation about google contact api, google maps API, but never a direct documentation on how to use names and addresses text to query the API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no specific API that can do what you'd like. However, there are few combinations of API that can be used in order to achieve the desired result:

1. **[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) + [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):**

   The use case would be the autocomplete will help the user to select
   the establishment that you would like to get the phone number, after
   selecting the location, the Place ID of the selected location will
   be supplied in the Place details request which will return the phone
   number of the establishment in the result.
2. **[Find Place From Query](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query) + [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):**

   The use case for this one would be like the first one but this can
   be a less reliable as  this will not have autocomplete function and
   will mostly rely on what the user supplied in the query but same as
   the first one, the Place ID returned from Find Place request will be
   supplied to the Place Details request.

You may also visit the [Pricing sheet](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use) to know how would it cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you have addresses of the restaurants, then you can use a [Find Place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) request to get the place_ID of the establishment, and then use a [Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request  to check for the [formatted_phone_number](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields) field.

Find Place Sample :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=mcdonalds+new+york+1st+street&inputtype=textquery&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Yields

```
{
  "candidates":[
    {
      "place_id":"ChIJcWEq7nVZwokRCaffM0Bqu8o"
    }
  ],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

The resulting place IDs can be used for a Place Details request that specifically requests for a formatter_phone_number :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJcWEq7nVZwokRCaffM0Bqu8o&fields=formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Yields

```
{
  "html_attributions":[

  ],
  "result":{
    "formatted_phone_number":"(212) 477-9171"
  },
  "status":"OK"
}
```